# Clunking noise at back wheel

Tags: wheels

My car(Ford puma) is making a clunking noise on the back passenger side wheel when I go over bumps and like a whering noise when I go round left hand corners?

Comment: A failed suspension bush could cause the tire to rub on something during cornering...

Comment: If the left side wheel is making the noise and it makes it when you make left-hand turn, it might be easy to see evidence that the tire is rubbing on the fender.

Answer (score 2):

Check your rear wheel bearings.  As it makes noise turning left, I'd start with the right hand rear wheel.  You can check them by jacking that car up (safely, with axle stands) and checking the wheel for free play and a lack of smoothness when turning it by hand.